# Web APP flask Application is not working because of "Exception: Install 'email_validator' for email validation support."

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web-applications, virtualenv

I need your hel with something.
I am creating a web application using flask , and I am working on my sign up page and when the user succesfully signs up it redirects them to the home page with a flask message.

I keep getting the error message "Exception: Install 'email_validator' for email validation support." ,In my virtual environment I have "email-validator" by running "pip install email-validator  "
and when I even try it again it says the following
`Requirement already satisfied: email-validator in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2.1.0.post1) Requirement already satisfied: dnspython>=2.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from email-validator) (2.4.2) Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from email-validator) (3.4)`

Here is my Python file "mypython.py"

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from forms import SignUpForm, SignInForm



app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '0e97339fb919eafaa1f4fa00351c0249'

@app.route('/') # For the Home Page
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home')

@app.route('/about') # For the about page
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About US')

@app.route('/contact') # For the contact Page
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html', title='Contact US')

@app.route('/faq') # For the FAQ Page
def faq():
    return render_template('faq.html', title='FAQ')

@app.route('/login') # For the Login Page
def login():
    return render_template('login.html', title='Log In')

@app.route('/pricing') # For the Pricing Page
def pricing():
    return render_template('pricing.html', title='Pricing')

@app.route('/signin', methods=['GET', 'POST']) # For the Sign In Page
def signin():
    form = SignInForm()
    return render_template('signin.html', title='Sign In', form=form)

@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST']) # For the Sign Up Page
def signup():
    form = SignUpForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       flash(f'Account Created for {form.firstname.DataRequired}!', 'success')
       return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('signup.html', title='Sign Up', form=form)

@app.route('/thank_you') # For the Thank You Page
def thank_you():
    firstname = request.args.get('firstname')
    lastname = request.args.get('lastname')
    return render_template('thankyou.html', firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

here is my forms.py

It holds two classes for the variables to use for sign in and logging in

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class SignUpForm(FlaskForm):
    firstname = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    lastname = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20), EqualTo('Password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')


class SignInForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Log In')
```

I have this block in my html file for the flash message.

```
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
        {% if messages %}
          {%  for category, message in messages %}
          <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}"> 
            {{ message }}
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}
```

I do not know what else to check, every were online it says to install email validator but I do have it on my virtual environment and I am not sure what else to check

I Tied to install "pip install email-validator  ", and it says it is already there and it did not fix the issue

Comment: Did you activate your virtual environment before installing ` email-validator`  and running Flask?

Comment: yes I did, I even tried to install it outside my virtual env on top of my virtual env

Comment: After activating your virtual environment run `which python` and `pip --version` in the terminal and check where they are pointing to. They should be pointing to your virtual environment folder. `$PROJECT_FOLDER/$VENV/Lib/site-packages/pip`

Comment: So I am not sure what it was, but Everything looked fine, so I decided to just delete my environment and create a new one and add what packages I want to install while creating it and that fixed my issue and it started working fine.